# Is it possible to specify an anonymous function's return type, in Scala?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, static-typing

I know you can create an anonymous function, and have the compiler infer its return type:

```
val x = () => { System.currentTimeMillis }
```

Just for static typing's sake, is it possible to specify its return type as well? I think it would make things a lot clearer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In my opinion if you're trying to make things more clear it is better to document the expectation on the identifier x by adding a type annotation there rather than the result of the function.

```
val x: () => Long = () => System.currentTimeMillis
```

Then the compiler will ensure that the function on the right hand side meets that expectation.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with *that the function on the left hand side meets that expectation*, setting a type for the result block also ensures that the type is correct, e.g. `val x = () => { System.currentTimeMillis } : String` does not compile. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Geoff's answer has the advantage that you get the full type up front.  If you have a long (multi-line) function definition, it's fastest to understand what's going on if the type is at the beginning.  Fabian's answer has the advantage of being less repetitive (esp. good for short (one-line) definitions, and faster to understand if you can grok the whole thing in one glance).

Comment: Oh, now I see Geoff's point, his type definition contains the input type, which here is `()`, and that gets checked when the function `() => System.currentTimeMillis` is assigned to `x`.

Comment: Yeah, that's it exactly. I really meant to say right hand side not left hand side.

Comment: Which is equivalent to `Function0[Long]`, though I usually prefer the shown notation.

Comment: I'm still studying Scala, and I'm in trouble in order to understand what is going on here. Why are there 2 `()`in the anonymous function definition? Or, are two anonymous functions being defined at the same time? Sorry for the necroposting.

Answer (score 59):

```
val x = () => { System.currentTimeMillis } : Long
```

Comment: This resolved my problem. This made a lot less verbose than using the Function# approach.

Comment: seems like `val x = () => Long = {blah}` would be a more intuitive syntax. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 13):

Fabian gave the straightforward way, but some other ways if you like micromanaging sugar include:

```
val x = new (() => Long) {
  def apply() = System.currentTimeMillis
}
```

or

```
val x = new Function0[Long] {
  def apply() = System.currentTimeMillis
}
```

or even

```
val x = new {
  def apply(): Long = System.currentTimeMillis
}
```

since in most situations it makes no difference if it descends from Function, only whether it has an apply.